# Не складываются 2 переменные руби

Tags: ruby

Задание

Напечатать на экран 5 раз слово Ruby. Вывод должен быть такое RubyRubyRubyRubyRuby

Есть переменные x = 5, y = "Ruby"

Мой код

```
print x * y
```

Почему-то выдаёт ошибку. Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чём дело?

Answer (score 1):

**Вы пытаетесь умножить число на строку.**
Попробуйте такой код:

```
print y * x
```